# err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode with name 'cch16' already exists

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I change the version of chaincode install and instantiate everytime when i want to do a startfabric. But when i change the version and run startfabric script i am getting the below error.

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode with name 'scbcch16' already exists
```

I have given the below commands, though I am getting the same error.

1. docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
2. docker rmi -f (*chaincode image ids*)
3. docker volume prune
4. docker network prune
5. docker system prune
6. I have down the byfn channel also

but still the get the same error.

Please find the chaincode list in my couch db fauxton as well.

[image: Chaincode name list in CouchDB Fauxton]

Is this due to any cache or is there any way to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To clean your entire docker resources, it should be enough with:

```sh
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker system prune -af --volumes
```

If there are some volumes mapped to specific directories, you must remove those folders manually.

Anyway, your base problem is probably that you are trying to instantiate again instead of **upgrade**: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-upgrade